# Find range of coefficient of the second degree x given f(x) has certain number of real roots?

Tags: functions

Given $f(x)=x^3-ax^2+x $, how do I find the range of $a$ if:

> 1. $f(x) \text{ has one real root}$
> 2. $f(x) \text{ has two distinct real roots }$
>
> and
>
> 3. $f(x) \text{ has three distinct real root}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint:* $f(x)=x(x^2-ax+1)$. So one root is easy and the analysis reduces to a quadratic.